# Access device camera exposure value before taking a picture

Tags: ios

I'm using the wonderful [GPUImage framework](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) from Brad Larson and I have at a certain point an instance of a AVCaptureDevice (property inputCamera from GPUImageVideoCamera class)  that I want to read the actual exposure value from before taking the picture, like in the metadata information that is created but only after the picture is taken. Is there a way to get this value live?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up an AVCaptureSession, then you can get the exposure data in real time from:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer  fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{

   lightSamp++;
   if(lightSamp>30){
      CFDictionaryRef metadataDictionary = CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
      NSDictionary *metaDict= (__bridge NSDictionary*)metadataDictionary;

      NSLog(@"exposure %@",metaDict );
      lightSamp=0;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: From what I understand that is only possible from a AVCaptureVideoDataOutput instance, not a AVCaptureStillImageOutput, is that right?

Comment: Yes I think that is correct. However, you can switch between video and still capture in the AVCaptureSession. It will introduce a short lag though.

Comment: Thanks, I've spent a lot of time trying to get exif from `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`. I used `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` with `CVImageBufferRef` functions and `CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex` returned nil. And you do this in 2 lines of code in main entry function `captureOutput`.