# iOS camera preview color temperature

Tags: ios, camera, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

Is it somehow possible to get the white balance color temperature (and tint) from a camera preview or from a saved picture?

I am able to get other exposure values in real time [based on this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743046/access-device-camera-exposure-value-before-taking-a-picture), like f-stop, exposure time, ISO, etc. The white balance always returns just 0, probably meaning "auto white balance". When I save an image from live preview the EXIF data has the white balance still just a zero.

I need to get the white balance color temperature in Kelvins the image/live camera preview was balanced to. I read some stuff about hidden APIs to get/set color temperature, but I cannot use hidden APIs. Any ideas if/how is this possible on iOS 7? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I'm afraid it's not possible (at least not without the hidden APIs to which you refer—and they don't use degK, but some internal system). And yes, 0 is the code for Auto white balance (1 would be manual).

Comment: Is there a way to somehow guess the colour temperature from an image? This sounds crazy to me, but there are some iOS apps that can change the white balance on the fly (effect visible directly on the live preview). Setting a new WB is not a problem, but how could they guess the old value?

Comment: I played a bit more with such an app and it does not set WB in Kelvins. It just says so, but the real thing is that is assumes that the current color temperature is 6500K and adjusts from there. It is a pure fake.

Comment: Yep, they're just post-processing filters, in fact—the actual WB of the camera module remains unchanged. Any numbers in degK will be wild guesses...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's possible to get values with the current API, you can check this out if you're still interested.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/whitebalancetemperatureandtintvalues

Comment: Is this a real-time value accessible from camera preview?

Comment: Yes, this is returned by the capture device(which is the camera). Although I don't think you'll be able to find out temperature and tint values for already saved images. Check this out https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624640-temperatureandtintvalues